# Processing all items in a collection even if one fails but ensuring the transaction is rolled back on each failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, transactions

I am trying to process a list of items but on some situations, an item can fail. I want to store the errors but continue to process the other items. I plan on raise them later. The code I have below doesn't seem to rollback changes if the one fails.

I'm wrapping the `process_item!` in a transaction which I expect the rollback to happen. I have a rescue around that to capture the error to process later

```
  def process(item, errors)
    begin
      transaction do
        process_item!(item) <-- adds this item to a other models but should rollback on failure
      end
    rescue StandardError => ex
      errors << ex
    end
  end

  def process_items(items)
    errors = []
    items.each do |item| <=== these should continue to process even if one fails
      process(item, errors)
    end
    errors
  end
```

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't seem to rollback changes if one fails? Also, it's good practice to rescue errors more specifically, otherwise you risk rescuing erroneous things (StandardError will catch run-of-the-mill runtime errors like NoMethodError, ArgumentError, etc). In this case you could rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24218787/2981429)

Comment: I'm saying that, if the first item fails (say somewhere the end of `process_item!`) it will rollback any changes it made but process the other items in `items`

Comment: I don't see how that would not happen with your code ... maybe you can show an example? What happens if you pass it a list of 2 items, the first of which is valid and the second invalid?

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: Can you explain the desired behavior?